# HashMap can store only object key and value

Tags: java, hashmap

`HashMap` does not take primitive types for the key and value, but we can still store values of primitive types easily as follows:

```
HashMap h = new HashMap();

h.put(1,1);
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Learn about generics and interfaces. Your code should be `Map<Integer, Integer> h = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();`

Comment: yes java converts `int` to `Integer` by using auto-boxing and in-boxing so what you are expecting?

Comment: Your question is very unclear (and could do with better formatting too). Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

When you store primitives in a `HashMap` (or any `Collection`), they are boxed into their reference types. An `int` is boxed to an `Integer`.

Comment: downvoted for answering without a question.

Comment: Can we encourage this type of questions by answering them in seconds?

Answer (score 2):

That is because `1` is *autoboxed* to an `Integer` (actually the same as this: `Integer.valueOf(1)`). Find more info about [autoboxing here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

- `int` is boxed to `Integer`
- `long` is boxed to `Long`
- `double` is boxed to `Double`
- `float` is boxed to `Float`
- `boolean` is boxed to `Boolean`

In your example you are using the *raw type* of the `Map`. The `Map`-object that you declared should most likely be declared like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> h = new HashMap<>();
h.put(1, 1);
```

Read more about *raw types* in this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Answer (score 1):

Primitives are autoboxed by the compiler and inserted as a wrapper object. So in your case it will be automatically boxed as Integer object. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for details. Every primitive type has corresponding wrapper object with some of them like:

```
primitive - Object  
   byte   -  Byte
   char   -  Character
   short  -  Short
   int    -  Integer
   long   -  Long
   double -  Double
   float  -  Float
   boolean - Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

> As any Java programmer knows, you can't put an int (or other primitive
>   value) into a collection.
>
> Collections can only hold object references,
>   so you have to box primitive values into the appropriate wrapper class
>   (which is Integer in the case of int).
>
> When you take the object out of
>   the collection, you get the Integer that you put in; if you need an
>   int, you must **unbox** the Integer using the intValue method. All of this
>   boxing and **unboxing** is a pain, and clutters up your code.
>
> The
>   **autoboxing** and **unboxing** feature automates the process, eliminating the
>   pain and the clutter.

[refer java docs for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html)